# jquery animate queue , the queue off only for a specific item

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have applied animations for the display of elements on the page.

The problem arose when I pressed the button to display the signup form if the animation of the next section was still going on and I pressed the button "Signup", the opening of the section that contained the form he had as a delay waiting for the end of animation in the bottom section.

So I applied to the animation :

```
$(document.body).on('appear', '.animate-from-left', function() {
        jQuery(this).each(function() {
            jQuery(this).delay(150).animate({opacity: 1, left: "0px"}, {duration: 2000, queue: false});
        });
    });
```

But now comes another small problem , the animations are not waiting anymore, so if I scroll quickly the DOM, start animations on all items.

So the question is :

can I make sure that the animations are not just waiting when I select the button of the opening section of the form- signup?

I hope I was clear.

Here is an example of the problem :[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lughino/LXh5M/2/)

If you select the signup button before the animation ends the section below , the opening will be delayed !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I found the solution!

```
$('#open-signup').on('click', function(){
    $('.animate-from-left').dequeue();
    $('.animate-from-right').dequeue();
    $('.animate-from-top').dequeue();
    $('.animate-from-bottom').dequeue();
    $(this).dequeue();
    ....
```

Here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lughino/LXh5M/3/).